# If a rogue planet entered near Jupiter planet could it tear the planet apart?

Tags: density, rogue-planet

Theoretically, there could be a rogue planet made of iron or even osmium in large quantities, which can make it have 25 Earth masses within the volume of 1 Earth Radii. So if this object came near Jupiter, would it be enough to absorb the matter from Jupiter at close orbits due to high density and would this rogue planet basically turn into a gas giant or is the tidal forces not high enough?

So assume that the rogue planet orbits within 20 km of Jupiter's surface.

Also if this rogue planet crashed into Jupiter, would it survive all the way and turn Jupiter into an accretion disk around it?

Is this planet basically just like a black hole except much less dense and massive but still very destructive and could it rip the sun into a bunch of gas due to object's immense density and surface gravity and turn it into an accretion disk or would this object get torn by the Sun?

Comment: Jupiter is worth 317 M, it will likely just absorb a 25M planet if it collides - this object you suggested weighs a mere 8% of its total mass. If it passes by without being absorbed, however, then perhaps it will strip some mass.

Comment: What if it was orbiting Jupiter at 100 kilometers above its surface? Would Jupiter lose mass to the planet?

Comment: It might be stripped a bit, but overall Jupiter should have more influence

Comment: Why would a rogue planet go into orbit around Jupiter? How does it lose enough velocity to do that?

Comment: "Theoretically" a planet could not be made of osmium, because there is no process that could separate the osmium in the dust orbiting a young star and form it into a planet.  So this is not a possibility in theory.

Comment: When you say jupiter's surface, do you mean like cloudtops, or..?

Comment: @James K it could still be an artificially constructed object made by aliens or somebody who were very bored because they had too much energy or something so they didn't want to run simulations on their computers so they did real life simulations by dropping planets on other planets.

Comment: @Darth Pseudonym I mean just above the cloud tops, there wouldn't be enough friction to bring the planet into Jupiter's gravity well.

Comment: No,  unless you are thinking of Magrathea,  but the galaxy isn't nearly wealthy enough yet.

Comment: It could also just be made of hyperdense iron and the pressure and gravity from the iron caused it to accumulate a lot of iron and nickel up to 25 masses of the Earth.